# HTML table triggers mouseOut on mouse move between TDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set mouseOut event handler on the table, but the event is triggered if I move the mouse over the TDs.
How to prevent the table flicker between the TDs? 
http://jsfiddle.net/2ZRBx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the jQuery Event API instead of the inline event triggering you use now. If you use the jQuery API it works correctly. Since you are using jQuery1.7.1:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#t").on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:1}, 200);
    });
}​);​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZRBx/6/

Comment: The key here is not to move the handler from inline javascript to jQuery events, but to use the mouseleave event instead of the mouseout. I you had used mouseout in the above code, the problem would still be present.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using jQuery, I'd remove the inline JavaScript and do this:

```
function go2() {
    $("#t").effect("pulsate", {
        times: 1
    }, 200);
}
$('#t').mouseleave(function() {
    go2();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2ZRBx/2/)**.

Comment: Why not use a JavaScript callback (as I suggested in my answer)? And getting 2 times the #t element out the of the DOM is really expensive time. Better is using `$(this)` in the `go2` function or save `$('#t')` in a variable and use that

Comment: You can checkout the docs on mouseleave and a good example of how jQuery's mouseout and mouseleave differ at http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the table in a div, then put the mouseout event on that div.